# How to do bar plot in the same scale and dimension as an image?

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I have an image, then I am projecting it on one of it's edges by some aggregation functions like `mean`. I am getting 1D digitized data this way. How to plot it exactly below source image in exactly the same horizontal or vertical scale?

Sample code:

```
% loading image
image = imread('..\..\FruitSample_small.png');

%computing gradients
dx=double(image(1:end-1,2:end,:))-double(image(1:end-1,1:end-1,:));
dy=double(image(2:end,1:end-1,:))-double(image(1:end-1,1:end-1,:));

% computing total magnitude
a=sqrt(sum(dx.^2,3)+sum(dy.^2,3));

% projection on bottom
h = mean(a,1);

% drawing
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
imshow(image);

subplot(2,1,2);

bar(h);
axis image;
```

I want bar plot here to be of the same width as image above. Also I want histogram to spread exactly to the same horizontal coordinate, as image does.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that "axis image" enforces an aspect ratio on the image axis, which allows the display size of the image to vary from its set dimensions.  My suggestion is to forget the auto-sizing capabilities that come from normalized units, and adjust the sizes based on pixel sizing.  If you set the size of the image axis to exactly the size of the image in pixels, then it will have the correct aspect ratio, and you can use the same size for the bar plot.

```
load clown; % use a built-in demo image.  Note the image is now in X

%computing gradients
dx=double(X(1:end-1,2:end,:))-double(X(1:end-1,1:end-1,:));
dy=double(X(2:end,1:end-1,:))-double(X(1:end-1,1:end-1,:));

% computing total magnitude
a=sqrt(sum(dx.^2,3)+sum(dy.^2,3));

% projection on bottom
h = mean(a,1);

% drawing
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
imagesc(X);
size_x = size(X,2);
size_y = size(X,1);
set(gcf, 'Units', 'pixels')
fp=get(gcf, 'Position');
set(gca, 'Units', 'pixels');
set(gca, 'Position', [(fp(3)-size_x) / 2, (fp(4)-size_y) / 2 + 100, ...
                      size_x, size_y]);

subplot(2,1,2);
bar(h);
set(gca, 'Units', 'pixels');
set(gca, 'Position', [(fp(3)-size_x) / 2, 100, size_x, 100]);
set(gca, 'XLim', [1 size_x]);
```

I'm computing the offsets automatically from the figure size, to center the results on the figure.  This is *not* resizeable.  You'd have to rerun the set('Position') stuff to readjust the locations if you resize the figure itself.  If you need it to be dynamically resizeable, you'd have to add a handler for a resize event, and adjust the sizes on every resize.